# string value from a checkbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm having trouble getting the value from my checkbox instead of showing me the boolean value of true or false how can I get it to take the value and show it on the screen in my table?

this is my checkBox:

```
<FormControlLabel
   label="Outro"
   control={
     <Checkbox
      id="outro"
      checked={Boolean(state.outro)}
      value="outro"
        onChange={() =>
        etState({
         ...state,
         outro: !Boolean(
         state.outro
   ),
 })
 }
  />
 }
 />
```

i need take a value outro and put in my table

Comment: You'll need to show us the code for that `Checkbox` component.

Comment: Use checked property (event.target.checked).

Comment: What are you expecting from the data when it's checked or unchecked?